# How to call a JavaScript function named `call` from dart

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

Is there any way to call a JavaScript function named `call()` (in a nested object) from Dart or do I have to wait for Dart 2.0 from which the special handling of `call()` might get removed?

I have a JS Proxy like:

```dart
@JS()
class SomethingFancy {
  external String call();
}
```

But as `call()` can be used to turn an object into a function, it makes it impossible to access the function of the JS object.

If I could, I would change the name of the method in Dart, but that's not supported by `package:js`:

```dart
/// By default the dart name is used. It is not valid to specify a custom     
/// [name] for class instance members.
```

The error I get is:

`Uncaught Error: NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'call$0' (J.getSomethingFancy$1$x(...).call$0 is not a function)`

If the function didn't exist, the error would look like this:

`Uncaught Error: NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'callMe' (receiver.callMe is not a function)`

Other functions on the same object work just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prefix `call` with `JS$`:

```dart
@JS()
class SomethingFancy {
  external String JS$call();
}
```

`JS$` can be used as prefix to allow to access to JS names that conflicts with dart keywords.

Comment: Does this work with DDC? It complains `JS$call` is not a function, but Dart2JS does not. I remember seeing `JS$JS$` also means something but I can't find it now.